# Make list content available in a function environment

Tags: r

In order to avoid creating R functions with many arguments defining settings for a single object, I'm gathering them in a list,

```
list_my_obj <- list("var1" = ..., "var2" = ..., ..., "varN" = ...)
class(list_my_obj) <- "my_obj"
```

I then define functions that accept such a list as argument and inject the elements of the list in the function scope:

```
my_fun <- function(list_my_obj) {

  stopifnot(class(list_my_obj) == "my_obj")

  list2env(list_my_obj, envir=environment())
  rm(list_my_obj)

  var_sum <- var1 + var2
  (...)

}
```

Injecting the elements of the list in the function scope allows me to avoid calling them with `list_my_obj$var1, list_my_obj$var2`, etc, later in the function, which would reduce the readability of the code.

This solution works perfectly fine, however it produces a note when running `R CMD check`, saying "no visible binding for global variable" for `var1, var2, ... varN`.

To avoid such notes, one could just create new variables at the beginning of the function body "by hand" for each element of the list:

```
var1 <- list_my_obj$var1
(...)
varN <- list_my_obj$varN
```

but I would like to avoid this because `N` can be large.

Any better solution or idea on how to suppress the R CMD check notes in this case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `with` (or `within`):

```
f <- function(x) {
   stopifnot(inherits(x, "my_obj"))
   with(x, {
      # ...
      var_sum <- var1 + var2
      # ...
      var_sum
   })
}

my_obj <- structure(list(var1 = 1, var2 = 2), class = "my_obj")
f(my_obj)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I like it. I was wondering though how this solution can be elegantly implemented (or whether there would be another solution) for those cases where the second argument of `with` (the expression) is a very large chunk of code, and for those cases where the elements of more than one object must be injected (`my_obj1, my_obj2`, ...). Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: (1) Modularize your code by using functions so that you don't have huge function bodies.  (2) `with(c(L1, L2), { ... })`

Comment: Ok, I'll try this! Thanks a lot for your suggestion

Comment: I have one last question regarding `with`. I noticed that it does copy-on-write. In my case, I'm updating the elements of `x` and returning some of them. So, even though I don't need `x` anymore I'm using twice the amount of memory taken by `x`. This is a problem as I'm handling very large objects. In my initial solution, I was able to delete `x` from the beginning. Is there a way I could avoid this double memory consumption using `with`? Or what would you advise then? Many thanks again!

Comment: You can update the input in-place by passing an environment instead of a list.  `with` also works with environments.  If `my_obj` is a list then: `my_obj_env <- list2env(my_obj); class(my_obj_env) <- c("my_obj", "environment"); rm(my_obj); f(my_obj_env)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm not sure if I have understood correctly... I tried your solution but the memory consumption is still twice that of `my_obj`. I guess that this is because `with` still does a copy of the environment `my_obj_env`, `my_obj_env_copy`, and when a value in `my_obj_env_copy` gets modified, all objects in `my_obj_env_copy` are stored somewhere in the memory... Right?

Comment: I think you will need to demonstrate your claim with a reproducible example since it is not true that updating a component of an environment causes the entire environment to be copied.  You can use `pryr::inspect` to investigate this.

Comment: As far as I can tell the environment is copied but this represents a shallow copy of its members. If you try to make any change to one of its members, a deep copy of the member is done.

Comment: If I do: 
`f <- function(x) { 
x_env <- list2env(x)
class(x_env) <- c("my_obj", "environment")
print(pryr::mem_used()) # 1
rm(x)
print(pryr::mem_used()) # 2
out <- with(x_env, {
  var1_copy <- var1
  print(pryr::mem_used()) # 3
  var1[1,1] <- 0
  print(pryr::mem_used()) # 4
  })
}

n <- 1e3; p <- 1e5; var1 <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow=n)
my_obj <- structure(list("var1" = var1, "var2" = 1:10), class = "my_obj")
f(my_obj)`   I get 
873 MB
873 MB
873 MB
1.67 GB

(Sorry for the formatting…)

Comment: The code creates a new variable and updates it so obviously both the new and old variable will take up space. That has nothing to do with `with`.

Comment: The memory after creating `var1_copy` is still 873MB. The memory consumption is doubled after that, when I update `var1`. In my case, I don't need to store the initial value of `var1` but only the updated `var1`. With the solution of first calling `list2env(my_obj, envir = environment()); rm(my_obj)`, I was able to limit the RAM consumption to 873MB, but of course it is not very transparent (at least according to `R CMD check`...). Sorry, I'm not sure if I'm clear enough in with these explanations....can you follow me? Thanks

Comment: The `print` statements provided in the code in your comment do not support the claim. There are two distinct variables so obviously they take up twice as much space.  This has nothing to do with `with`.

Comment: Replacing the above `f` with: `f <- function(x) { x_env <- list2env(x); class(x_env) <- c("my_obj", "environment"); rm(x); print(pryr::mem_used()); out <- with(x_env, { var1[1,1] <- 0; print(pryr::mem_used()) }) }` produces 873 MB 1.67 GB. This modifies `var1` in-place in the environment of the `with` block, and there is obviously a copy, at least of `var1`.

Comment: Try this:  `x_env <- list2env(my_obj); pryr::mem_used(); x_env$var1[1,1] <- 0; pryr::mem_used()` and we see that it uses some additional memory but have not used `with`.

Comment: In fact, try this:  `var1 <- my_obj$var1; pryr::mem_used(); var[1,1] <- 1; pryr::mem_used()`

Comment: All this makes sense to me. The issue I'm concerned with is that the memory consumption is doubled anyway. I don't need the initial values in my_obj_env once I've updated them. The with option, although it is very elegant, prevents me from deleting them :/

Answer (score 10):

The function `list2env` is made for this, for example:

`list2env(list_my_obj, env = environment())`

Comment: Right, calling environment() with no arguments "then the current evaluation environment is returned."